# Im trying to prevent getting expected errors but "try-except" stopped working

Tags: python, return, try-catch, project, except

I really don't know whats happening.

Yesterday i wrote the 800th line for my project and everything gone perfect.

Every **"Try: - except:"** i had written yesterday, and test it thousand times, today do not work.

It gives me errors i already stated inside except.

For every single try-except inside my code not only one.

Something gone really bad but i cant think something..

```
Try:
    self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(“temp/“+row_id+”.png”))
    self.canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=“n”, image= self.img)
    self.canvas.image = self.img 
except UnidentifiedImageError:
    message box.showinfo(“….”)
```

I get an UnidentifiedImageError in the 1st line after try.

**Minimal Example:**

```
import socket
PORT = 5000
SERVER = "192.168.1.110"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

try:
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(ADDR)  
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    #do something
    pass
except TimeoutError:
    #do something
    pass
```

Im still getting both **ConnectionRefusedError** and **TimeoutError** .
It was expected , but, thats why we use "except" right?

[image: Check this photo]

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Try catching global exception using `except Exception` and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: Update your question posting a stack trace along with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating that your try/except blocks do not work.

Comment: Yash, except Exception sadly does not work more that the other exceptions .

Comment: If you explicitly `raise` an exception, does that get caught? If it does, I'd suspect that for some reason your `socket` module has a different idea of what `ConnectionRefusedException` is than the rest of your program. Perhaps try a bare `except:` clause and dig out the caught object from `sys.exc_info()`, print the id of the type of the object actually caught, and compare with the id of `ConnectionRefusedException`.

Comment: Ture Pålsson i will try, but, what about PhotoImage exceptions? It is not only about sockets but in general all my try-excepts do not catch the exceptions. Something deeper happened but i cannot detect it.